# Streaming Json - PushStreamContent with a Large Object

Tags: c#, json, stream, streaming, pushstreamcontent

I need to stream a large object.  I'm unable to figure out how to send it in chunks.  The posted code works, however, *stream.Flush()* only gets called once.  So, essentially I'm buffering the object - not good.  How do I call *stream.Flush()* multiple times?  If I had a collection, I could stream/flush in a loop.  So how do I do that with a large object?

SERVER CODE:

```
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ConvertToTiffAsync([FromBody] DocumentDto dto)
                {
                    // THIS IS LARGE
                    var document = await _service.ConvertToTiffAsync(dto);
                    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
                    response.Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
                    {
                        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                        {
                            using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
                            {
                                serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, document);
                                stream.Flush(); // ONLY CALLED ONCE - NEED MANY CALLS
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return response;
                }
```

CLIENT CODE (streaming not happening here, but needs to):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
            {
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
                var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint))
                {
                    httpRequest.Content = stringContent;
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
                        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                        {
                            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                            return await Task.Run(() => serializer.Deserialize<ConvertDocumentDto>(jsonReader)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You don't need to flush. What PushStreamContent does is basically all data that gets written to it is directly streamed to the client without buffering the contents. So are you sure the complete JSON representation is in the memory?

Comment: Also according to https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2013/11/30/uploading-data-with-httpclient-using-a-push-model/ if you want to stream JSON, instead of a PushStreamContent you could just use new ObjectContent(document, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()) which should do the same but is much more concise.

Comment: @ckuri...that article is focused on uploading not downloading. Also, I don't believe the data is streamed until flush() is called - at least that's the way I'm seeing it when I run the code.

Comment: It works the same for upload and download as in both cases subclasses of HttpContent are used.

Comment: The flush wouldn't matter anyway as a the StreamWriters Dispose method which is called when you leave the using block always calls the streams flush method. So this line is redundant. What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: @ckuri...please look at my edits

Comment: What is the actual purpose of the client code as it doesn't seem to be able to consume the server the response? It's neither reading the response nor does it deserialize it. It's just serializing and as it is not using the JsonTextWriter (just instantiating it), but serializing the complete document to a string it would use lots of memory.

Comment: As it would be to long to write as a comment, please take a look at my answer how making a request to the sever and consuming a large JSON response without having everything in memory would be like.

Answer (score 0):

Your server code seems to be fine. However, your client code doesn't seem to be able to properly interact with the server.

If you want to set DocumentDto input, you would need to write the JSON to the request, not to the response. If you want to consume the server action without having the complete JSON in memory you would need a JsonTextReader. So in general in the client-side should be:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var dtoContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) => {
   var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
       using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
       { serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, dto); }
    }
});
using (var stream = await client.PostAsync(url, dtoContent).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
    {
        document = JsonSerializer().Deserialize<Document>(jsonReader);
    }
  }
}
```

If your DTO is small and you don't mind having the complete JSON in memory instead of client.PostAsync(url) you could also use client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, dto) which is in the HttpClientExtensions namespace if you import System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll.

Comment: Sorry, but I posted the wrong code for the client.  The actual code id there now and doesn't stream.